# Using a button to switch between view controllers on different tabs (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1 not working)

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm a bit new to XCode, so I'm not exactly sure what I did wrong. So thank you in advance to anyone who is willing to help me out :)

I have 2+ view controllers imbedded in a tab bar controller, and each vc is imbedded in a navigation controller, and I want to use a button in a vc to switch to another vc in a different tab. Actually, I was able to do this in a past project: I created an IBAction function that switches to a different tab when a button is pressed. Below is what my code looked like (and it worked with no problems at all)

```
@IBAction func ButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

**However**, it's not working anymore, and I don't know if I did anything differently. Is there a way around this? (Or maybe why this might not be working anymore?)

If that description was a bit confusing, I included a screenshot of what I'm trying to do.

[I'm trying to get from the top view controller to the bottom with when the button in the first vc is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnAt3.png)

Answer (score 1):

if you're in a navigation controller you might need to do this:
`self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1`

Comment: just tried it and worked for me when embedded in a navigation controller

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I typed it in, but it just gives an error that says "value of type 'InitialViewController' (which is the view controller with the button) has no member 'selectedIndex'"